# Facebook messenger api, Handover protocol

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

My bot is the primary reciever and the page inbox is secondary.

Messages from the user is placed correctly in the done folder, but when the bot replies its moved out to the inbox.

Anyone else experienced something similar to this?

Comment: This happens after thread control is passed back to the primary?

Comment: No, the messages from the user goes into the done folder as expected and when the bot replies the conversation is back in the page inbox instead of still in the done folder. In devolopment this worked fine and the messages only showed up in the page inbox if someone requested help by pressing a button that passes the thread to the page inbox.

Comment: Can you open a bug report on this and add the Messenger Platform tag? 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/